# avoid select value manipulation

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to avoid any manipulation on a select with an html inspector.

my code:

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I submit it to the database like this:

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO option (select) VALUES(?)');
$statement->execute(array($select));
```

if someone changes the "value" part of an option it submits the manipulated option value. how can I fix that?

Comment: You can't avoid manipulation, but you can make sure in your PHP that you only run the query when `$_POST['select']` is either 1 or 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should never trust data from the frontend. Always check the values on the backend. Like

```
$select = intval($_POST['select']);
if( $select === 1 || $select === 2)
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO option (select) VALUES(?)');
    $statement->execute(array($select));
}
else
{
    // something is fishy
}
```

EDIT: (to cover the comments)

The inputs have some acceptable bounds or values. Whether it is exactly [1,2, or 5] or anything between 1 and 100000000 does not matter. You set up boundary checks, check against the DB etc. to make sure you get back an acceptable value.

The code above is simplified. Check the type you are getting. If you expect an integer, do an `intval($var)` to be sure you are getting int. Check the length of the strings as well. Look here for more info: https://www.guru99.com/equivalence-partitioning-boundary-value-analysis.html

Comment: Strict type checks for integers will probably fail when working with posted form data. Everything is posted as strings (which means that $select would never be === 1, but will be == 1). The form can't know if you meant it to be an integer or a string.

Comment: how would I go if there are like 50 options to choose from? is there any more beautiful way than putting every option into one if?

Comment: @CunnertA — Use a database

Comment: You should probably also update the code in the answer to be functional (which it currently isn't, since the if-statement would always evaluate as false) and to reflect your comment underneath it.

Comment: @Quentin what about performance? wouldnt it be bad performance wise?

Comment: @CunnertA — Databases are fast. Worry about performance problems when you have performance problems. Until then, writing clear maintainable code is a virtue.

Comment: @cunnertA It is always a tradeoff, do you rather want security and data integrity problems, or do you want sacrifice a bit of performance.

Comment: so I did this: created a table with available options, on submit I check if rowcount is 1, if not it spits out an error, if yes it goes through. this sould be a proper way I guess @Quentin

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to avoid any manipulation on a select with an html inspector.

You can't. What happens in the user's browser is not your concern. You are not the user. It is **their** browser.

You have no control over what gets submitted to your HTTP end points.

You can only write server-side code to react to it. e.g. to return an error message if an unacceptable value is submitted.